# C# Web Service project to load dependent DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have been given a web service project to work on and I've made it reference a dll. This dll has several other dll's it is dependent on to load. For any other application I've used that needed this dll, I just slapped the dependent dll's in the bin folder. This doesn't seem to work for the web service application, and I get the error stating that "blah.dll failed to load because dependent dll blah blah". My question is where can I put these dependent dll's or what can I configure in visual studio for the web service to find and load the dependant dlls.

Thank you.

*Also, this is for debug purposes only, so the solution doesn't need to be the "correct" way. Anything hacky is fine, as long as I get it to work.

Comment: How do you deploy the web service?

Comment: Are you copying all of the dependencies into the deployment directory? How are you hosting / deploying the service?

Comment: What kind of web service? ASMX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you enable the "Copy Local" option on each reference to a non-standard dll. This will ensure that the dlls are copied into the bin directory when you build, and you can easily build a deployment from there. Assuming you are hosting under IIS, it should be as simple as zipping up the bin directory and moving it to your server application directory.